# Directive to show error messages

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have validation set up, and am using `ngMessages` to show errors. However I want to create a wrapper directive around `ngMessages` that adds some HTML (to avoid a lot of code duplication).

So instead of having to write this on each input:

```
<div class="help-block validator">
    <div ng-messages="registerForm.email.$error" ng-if="registerForm.email.$touched">
        <p ng-message="required">This field is required.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd just write something like this:

```
<error-message messages='{"required": "This field is required."}' error="registerForm.email.$error" touched="registerForm.email.$touched"></error-message>
```

The issue with my directive is that `error` and `touched` come up as strings, they don't get evaluated as JS expressions. I've tried to `$eval` them, but that throws an error.

Here's my directive:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive("errorMessage", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                'messages': '=',
                'error': '=',
                'touched': '='
            },
            template: '<div class="help-block validator">' +
                '<div ng-messages="error" ng-if="touched">' +
                    '<div ng-repeat="(key, message) in messages">' +
                        '<p ng-message="key">{{message}}</p>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.error = attrs.error;
                scope.touched = attrs.touched;
                scope.messages = scope.$eval(attrs.messages); // this works
            }
        };
    });
```

Any idea how I should go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. Looks like `attrs` wasn't what I needed. The properties were already in the `scope`. The code I ended up with is:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive("errorMessage", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                'messages': '=',
                'error': '=',
                'touched': '='
            },
            template: '<div class="help-block validator">' +
                '<div ng-messages="error" ng-if="touched">' +
                    '<div ng-repeat="(key, message) in messages">' +
                        '<p ng-message="{{key}}">{{message}}</p>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [ng-message-include](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages#reusable-ngmessages-with-file) meets your requirements.  we can create new html file and place all of our messages in this file and just call it with ng-messages-include.

hope my answer is usable for you.